# jQuery How to duplicate inputs fields based on number from another input?

Tags: jquery, clone

So here is problem,

I have code like this in php

```
<?php
foreach ($products as $product): ?>
<tr>
 <td><?= $this->Form->input('product_'.$product->id, ['id' => 'product_'.$product->id, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']); ?></td>
 <td><?= $product->name ?></td>
 <td><?= $product->name ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the list of all elements first column is input field - number. I want when somebody type number 5 in first input (first iteration) that jQuery automatically clone 5 times that input with unique ID-s, also when type 7 in another input, that clone 7 times another input etc.

So I have tried following

```
var wrapper = $(".selected-products"); //Fields wrapper
<?php
foreach($products as $product):
?>
  $('#product_<?= $product->id ?>').empty();
  var qty = $('#product_<?= $product->id ?>').val();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < qty; ++i) {
    $(wrapper).append(
      '<div class="item-border">'+
        '<div class="col-sm-12">'+
          '<h3><?= $product->name ?></h3>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="col-sm-6">'+
          '<?= $this->Form->input('type_'.$product->id, ['label' => __('Container action'), 'options' => $containerAction, 'default' => '1', 'id' => 'type_'.$product->id, 'class' => 'form-control']) ?>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>'
    ); //add input box
  }
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

And products ar e here

```
<div class="selected-products"></div>
```

But if i go one step back and go forward (without refresh), how can I delete previous changes (generated fields) and set new one

Thx

Comment: what you've tried so far ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is that sufficient as an answer?